# Could I configure IntelliJ diff viewer/merge tool as external tools in tortoiseSVN?

Tags: intellij-idea, merge, tortoisesvn, diff

New `IntelliJ` diff viewer and merge tools are awesome. I'm wondering if I could configure them as external tools in tortoiseSVN.

I tried it setting intelliJ executable as external Diff Viewer in tortoiseSVN configuration...but it doesn't work.

[image]

Also I've been reading the IntelliJ [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html#d665954e250) (Running IntelliJ IDEA as a Diff or Merge Command Line Tool) but I'm not sure how to configure it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Re-read [Comparing files using intellij idea as a diff command line tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html#d665954e178) until there will come enlightenment in getting correct command-line

> ```
> <IntelliJ IDEA launcher> diff <path to file1> <path to file2>
> ```
>
> where `file1` is your local copy, `file2` is the repository version.

for external diff for TortoiseSVN, there you have to use `%base` (repository-side file) and `%mine` (modified file in WC) variables as placeholders for compared files.

You addded nothing (nor command, nor parameters) into your command line, thus - got nothing

**Answer**

```
/path/to/idea diff %mine %base
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much

Comment: I would recommend swapping `%mine` and `%base` but that's up to personal preference.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to configure the merge tool, use this configuration:

```
/path/to/idea merge %mine %theirs %base %merged
```

Comment: I've got it setup like you described and everything looks fine, but when clicking on "accept" the changes aren't saved. Any idea why this happens?